# Getting Random Permission Errors with Google App Script, How to Debug?

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a librairy with a bunch of code that accesses my spreadsheet and my google drive. I tested it and it worked, now it's not working. I read 20 SO threads about how to fix it, nothing is working. How do I debug this?

I've gotten this error "You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)
" as well as the same error for "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet". It seems to be intermittent when I delete and reauthorize code. Where are these authorization stored?

Here's my code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Scripts")
    .addItem("Sync Drive", "GAppsUtils.syncDrive")
    .addItem("Download Selected Scripts", "GAppsUtils.downloadSelectedScripts")
    .addToUi()
}
```

In my "GAppsUtils" librairy:

```
function copyFilesToFolder(files, folder) {
  for (var i in files) {
    var file = files[i]
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), folder)
  }

  return folder
}

function createTempFolderFromFiles(files) {
  var tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDERS.TEMP)
  var tempSubFolder = tempFolder.createFolder('download_' + Date.now())
  copyFilesToFolder(files, tempSubFolder)
  return tempSubFolder
}

function getSelectedCellValues() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var selection = activeSheet.getSelection()
  var selectionValues = selection.getActiveRange().getValues()

  var range = selection.getActiveRange()
  var firstRowIndex = range.getRow()

  var unfilteredSelectionValues = []
  for (var i in selectionValues) {
    i = Number(i)
    if (!activeSheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + firstRowIndex)) {
      unfilteredSelectionValues.push(selectionValues[i])
    }
  }

  return unfilteredSelectionValues
}

function downloadSelectedScripts() {
  var selectedValues = getSelectedCellValues()
  var scriptFileNames = selectedValuesToScriptFileNames(selectedValues)
  var scriptFiles = getScriptFiles(scriptFileNames)
  var tempFolder = createTempFolderFromFiles(scriptFiles)
  Browser.msgBox(tempFolder.getUrl())
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the onOpen() with an installable onOpen trigger. [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)

Comment: @Cooper can you give an example? I don't get what an installable trigger is.

Comment: [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)